# Getting Succes Page directly

Tags: struts2

### DeleteAction.java

```java
public class DeleteAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String email;
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override

    public String execute(){
        UserManager um = new UserManagerImpl();
        try {
            um.deletestudent(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}`
```

i am new to coding and i am getting success page directly..please help me to solve the problem. i want to delete the data from the database.

Comment: What are you asking? If you're getting the success page then there was no exception during `deletestudent` (which should be named `deleteStudent`). If it didn't delete, then the problem lies in `deleteStudent`.

Comment: post yhe code which is written in your **`deletestudent`** function....